# Eclipse ADT - Unresolved inclusion jni.h

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

On my Windows platform, I have the latest version of adt bundle (20140321) and ndk (r9d) installed. The installation is as clean as it gets. The environment variables NDK_ROOT, PATH, etc. are all defined properly.

The app I am working on has some C++ native code. The code builds fine both outside Eclipse as well as within Eclipse.

The problem, however, is that the editor complains that jni.h is an unresolved inclusion.

Project-->Properties-->C/C++ General-->PathsAndSymbols shows include directories and one of the directories is C:\adt\ndk\platforms\android-19\arch-arm\usr\include. I have verified that jni.h is present in this directory.

I have already checked all other messages on this forum but couldn't find any concrete steps. Appreciate your guidance. Regards.

Answer (score 25):

I ran into a similar problem with a working project with Android NDK-based code after updating to Eclipse Kepler. I observed similar things: the header files would correctly be listed under "includes" in the project, the actual build (via ndk-build) worked fine, but Eclipse's editor couldn't locate any headers in standard system directories (all headers with < > brackets).

I tried many different fixes, including switching toolsets, rebuilding indices etc. without success.

Finally, I removed the C nature entirely from the project, and added it back via the "Android Tools" menu in Eclipse.

**Removing the C nature:**

The only way I could find to reliably removed the C nature from the project was by hand editing Eclipse's `.project` file for the project.

1. Close the Eclipse project (e.g. by quitting Eclipse).
2. Open the `.project` file in a text or xml editor. There will be at least 2 `<buildCommand>` nodes that need to be removed. Remove the `<buildCommand>` node with name `org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.genmakebuilder` and all its children, and the `<buildCommand>` node with name `org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.ScannerConfigBuilder` and its children. Finally, remove the lines:

   `<nature>org.eclipse.cdt.core.cnature</nature>`
   `<nature>org.eclipse.cdt.core.ccnature</nature>`
   `<nature>org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.managedBuildNature</nature>`
   `<nature>org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.ScannerConfigNature</nature>`
3. Completely remove the `.cproject` file.

**Adding back the Android Native nature**

Reopen the project in Eclipse. Then right-click on the project in the Project Explorer, and from the "Android Tools" contextual menu, choose "Add Native Support...".

[image: Android Tools -> Add Native Support...]

Looking at the changes made in the .project and .cproject files before and after this change, it appears that it primarily gave new version numbers to the Android NDK tools. In any case, it solved the issue for me.

Comment: Did the trick. I was importing some JNI projects into luna and I had unresolved jni.h and other problems. This has reset the project to my environment. Thank you.

Comment: This worked. I tried this to fix a similar error for Eclipse neon and it worked. I was stuck for days trying to fix many errors that sprouted from this error. Primarily property page related errors. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

after add native support,right click project, add includes in c/c++ general--> paths and symbols >> includes, for example add include as %NDK_HOME%\platforms\android-19\arch-arm\usr\include

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem some days ago. I found a fix in another question here in stackoverflow, but now I can't find the link.

In Eclipse: right-click on your project > Properties > C/C++ General > Code Analysis > Launching and disable both options ("Run with build" and "Run as you type").

There seems to be a problem with CDT and the Indexer, doing this you hide the problem. The editor will still complain but now you should be able to run and debug your application.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this for adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321:

1. No any environment variables is set, just pointed NDK location under Preferences > Android > NDK.
2. I created new, clean Eclipse workspace.
3. Deleted from my project with C++ code next files/folders:

> .settings
>  .classpath
>  .cproject
>  .project
>  project.properties

1. Eclipse > New > Other > Android > Android Project from Existing Code > then point folder with your project, let Eclipse detect it, check "Copy project into workspace" and click Ok/Next, whatever.
2. Clean project.
3. Right click on project > Android Tools > Add native support
4. Rebuild, possibly restart workspace.

Also this solved issue with Eclipse 4.3 previously ignored build system and user defined compiler flags. Now macros folding dependent on this flags etc works fine.

If more general - NDK plugin can properly define for you right includes and anything other required to work fine, but you need to clean your project from broken crap.