# Compiling Hello-Jni failure in eclipse only when opening the hello-jni.c file in eclipse

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have been trying endlessly to build the sample HelloJni sample project for the Android NDK.

**How I set up the environment:**

I followed the instructions of the getting started in the docs: android-ndk-r10d\docs\Getting_Started/html/index.html:

1. Downloaded Eclipse **Luna**
2. Downloaded the Android SDK
3. Downloaded the Android NDK: **android-ndk-r10d**
4. Set the NDK installation folder in eclipse in preferences window -> android -> NDK.
5. Imported the hellp-jni sample.
6. Right click on the HelloJni Project -> Android tools -> Add native support.
7. Cleaned and Built the project.
8. Ran on my device the HelloJni library (not the tests)

And the app is running and everything is WORKING and I can see the generated .so file per architecture in the libs folder of the project (for every architecture, for example armebi, mips, etc...)

Here is a Print Screen showing **everything is working:**

[image]

Now here comes the strange part...

**The Problem:**

If I open the hello-jni.c file for editing or viewing in eclipse, I suddenly see compilation errors and I can't build and can't run the project anymore...

Here is a Print Screen showing that after i open the file, I suddenly get compilation errors:

[image]

**What I have already tried but failed:**

1. Adding the Android Native Nature, then removing it by:
   Deleting the .project file, 
   the buildCommand tag of: org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.genmakebuilde, 
   the buildCommand tag of: org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.ScannerConfigBuilder 
   and removing the lines: 
   [nature]org.eclipse.cdt.core.cnature[/nature] 
   [nature]org.eclipse.cdt.core.ccnature[/nature] [nature]org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.managedBuildNature[/nature] [nature]org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.ScannerConfigNature[/nature]
   removing the .cproject and all compiled files.
   Then adding back the Android Native Nature.

According to this stackoverflow link:
[Eclipse ADT - Unresolved inclusion jni.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122934/eclipse-adt-unresolved-inclusion-jni-h/23729649#23729649)

Failed

2. Once I got the error of (I am not getting it anymore): Unable to launch cygpath. Is Cygwin on the path?] java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cygpath". So I Googled and I changed the build settings to give the absolute path of my NDK installation folder:

According to this stackoverflow link:
[Unable to launch cygpath in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459934/unable-to-launch-cygpath-in-android)

Here is a Print Screen:
[image]

Failed

3. Changing the Used tools from Android GCC Compiler to GCC C Compiler

according to this stackoverflow link: 
[Android NDK build, Method could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155676/android-ndk-build-method-could-not-be-resolved/23158929#23158929)

Here is a Print Screen:
[image]

Failed

4. Copying an eclipse Luna installation from a friend that has the project working for him.

Failed

I have been spending hours on this and I couldn't find any solution to why this is happening.

**PLEASE HELP**

Comment: I also wonder if Android-Studio can import and create projects that use NDK .

Comment: assuming you aren't getting any errors, did you do `static { System.loadLibrary("your.so"); }`

Comment: Yes, this is the sample project it has it:
static {
        System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
    }

Comment: @FeatheredOrcian Since he said he tried the NDK sample called "helloJni", if you look at the java file, they have this code called at the bottom :     static { System.loadLibrary("hello-jni"); } . Besides, he wrote the app works, and that only when he tries to edit the C/C++ file, problems appear.

Comment: Do a clean and look at the console tab (not the problem tab).  The console tab should show the progress of the NDK build process, this will most likely be clean. Your errors look like Eclipse CDT errors.  I don't think CDT is correctly setup by "Add Native Support". I usually have to set it up by hand.

Comment: Richard thanks for your help, when I do clean & build all, it does get built, and it generates the different *.so files under libs.
But since Eclipse is showing me that I have errors, I can't run the project, what do you suggest?
how can i solve my problem and "correctly setup and fix the Eclipse CDT errors" ?

Comment: Temporary fix is to highlight the error reports in the Problems tab and then press [Delete].  This will get rid these errors until you try and edit the file(s) in Eclipse again.  If you edit your C/C++ files outside of Eclipse (eg. use Notepad++) then the "fake" errors will not return.  Long term fix is to setup Eclipse CDT/Indexer to work correctly with Android-NDK.

Comment: Ok it is now building, but It is a problem programming like that, i might as well write in notepad++ :) how do you setup Eclipse CDT/Indexer to work correctly with Android-NDK, from my understanding there is some bug about it in: eclipse-4.3 + cdt-8.2.0 + adt-22.0.4. according to this link: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33788

Comment: I'm new to NDK, and I have the exact same problem. ZiviMagic, did you find a solution? @RichardCritten, where did you learn how to setup Eclipse to work with NDK?

Comment: @DannyA Didn't find a permanent solution. What I am doing is to simply delete all the errors in eclipse every time before I build.
This sucks, but no1 else replied and found an answer

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem when you try to edit a C/C++ file inside a JAVA workspace/perspective without the proper configuration. **You can simply select all the entries in the Error Log and delete them**.

Comment: Yes this works, but I was looking for a solution so I won't have to delete it each time...

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, Eclipse seems to have issues with the **r10d** version of Android NDK. See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=97023. I suggest you try **r10c** instead #worksforme :)

Comment: I have tried with r8 and it didn't work. I just moved to AS. and in the cases I want to use eclipse I delete the errors before I compile..
Thanks for the help though